# Why is it valid to multiply both sides of an equation by its complex conjugate?

Tags: complex-numbers

[This](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intuitive-arithmetic-with-complex-numbers/) is the closest explanation I can find, although I still don't fully understand.

> We know what’s happening: division is subtracting an angle and
>   shrinking the magnitude. By multiplying top and bottom by the
>   conjugate, we subtract by the angle of (1-i), which happens to make
>   the denominator a real number (it’s no coincidence, since it’s the
>   exact opposite angle). We scaled both the top and bottom by the same
>   amount, so the effects cancel. The result is to turn division into a
>   multiplication in the numerator.

What I understand so far is from a pseudo-example of real values. If you have an expression that is 1/5 = x, then if you multiply the left by c (in this case, 5) to get it to 1, you have to multiply the right by an equivalent value to get that side to 1. Extending the analogy to complex conjugates means that since (e^ix)(e^-ix)=1, you can just multiply each side by the complex conjugate to get both sides to one.

This implies that if two sides of a given expression are equal, then their complex conjugates are equal. Why is that true?

Comment: Complex conjugation is a function on $\mathbb C$. If you plug in the same number to a function multiple times, it gives you the same answer each time—that's the definition of a function. It doesn't matter if the two inputs look different; if they're actually the same, the outputs are also the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going straight to the last question:

> If two sides of a given expression are equal, then their complex conjugates are equal. Why is that true?

The idea here is that each side of the expression is a complex number.  That is, there are real numbers $a,b$ such that each side is equal to $a+bi$.  The conjugate of that number is $a - bi$.  So, the conjugate of each side, is equal to the number $a - bi$.